# C# - Attach FileStream in Sending to Email System.ObjectDisposedException

Tags: c#

Good day,

I'm trying to attach a filestream file to email sending attachment. The scenario is, I need to create a file using `FileStream` then attach it to my email.

So far here's my sample code:

For creating file:

```
public FileStream CreateFileStream(){
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
    var writer = new StreamWriter(ms);

    writer.WriteLine("file content blah blah blahh");
    writer.Flush();

    //You have to rewind the MemoryStream before copying
    ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

       using (var fs = new FileStream("Filename.txt", FileMode.Create))
       {
          ms.CopyTo(fs);
          return fs;
       }
    }
}
```

And here is my sample code for email sending

```
// attachment
var fileStreamFile = dto.FileStreamFile;

var contentType = new ContentType(MediaTypeNames.Text.Plain);
var attach = new Attachment(dto.FileStreamFile, contentType);
attach.ContentDisposition.FileName = "File.txt";

mail.Attachments.Add(attach);
...
// code for sending here
...
dto.FileStreamFile.Dispose(); // for disposing File Stream
```

`fileStreamFile` is not null but it throws an error that says,

`Handle = 'dto.FileStreamFile.Handle' threw an exception of type 'System.ObjectDisposedException'`

When I comment out the attach codes, the sending of email works fine anyway. The email sending fails when I include my code for attaching `FileStream`

Any help please? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code

```
using (var fs = new FileStream("Filename.txt", FileMode.Create))
{
    ms.CopyTo(fs);
    return fs; // you are returning here
} // hang on, this is a using statement which will dispose fs!
```

Will translate to this

```
FileStream fileStream = new FileStream("Filename.txt", FileMode.Create);
try
{
   return fileStream;
}
finally
{
   if (fileStream != null)
   {
      ((IDisposable)fileStream).Dispose();
   }
}
```

It's important to note, that if you `return` in a `try finally`, it stores the return value in a local variable, to return after the `finally`. Which will look something like this

```
FileStream fileStream = new FileStream("Filename.txt", FileMode.Create);
try
{
   temp = fileStream;
}
finally
{
   if (fileStream != null)
   {
      ((IDisposable)fileStream).Dispose();
   }
}

return temp;
```

We can take a look at the *IL* to see what's happening

```
IL_0000: ldstr "someFile"
IL_0005: ldc.i4.2
IL_0006: newobj instance void [mscorlib]System.IO.FileStream::.ctor(string, valuetype[mscorlib]System.IO.FileMode)
// stloc.0 Pops the current value from the top of the evaluation stack and stores it in the 
// local variable list at a specified index. This is your fs reference
IL_000b: stloc.0 
   .try
{
   // ldloc.0 Loads the local variable at a specific index onto the evaluation stack.
   // This is your fs reference
   IL_000c: ldloc.0
   // stloc.1 Pops the current value from the top of the evaluation stack and stores it in 
   // the local variable list at a specified index. This is your fs reference
   IL_000d: stloc.1
   IL_000e: leave.s IL_001a
} // end .try
finally
{
   IL_0010: ldloc.0
   IL_0011: brfalse.s IL_0019     
   IL_0013: ldloc.0
   // oh no we just Disposed fs!!!
   IL_0014: callvirt instance void [mscorlib]System.IDisposable::Dispose()
   IL_0019: endfinally
} // end handler

// ldloc.1 Loads the local variable at a specific index onto the evaluation stack.
// This is your fs reference
IL_001a: ldloc.1
//ret Returns from the current method, pushing a return value (if present) from 
//the callee's evaluation stack onto the caller's evaluation stack.
IL_001b: ret
```

In short, don't return an `IDisposable` reference from a `using` statement as it will get *disposed*.

You will need to create the `FileStream` (without the `using`) and `Dispose` it in another context, or refactor your code.

**Update**

> But my email sending doesn't work after I put a using statement
> covering the sending of email with stream

You maybe over-complicating this, try something like this

```
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
   using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream)) // using UTF-8 encoding by default
      using (var mailClient = new SmtpClient("localhost", 25))
         using (var message = new MailMessage("me@example.com", "you@example.com", "Just testing", "See attachment..."))
         {
            writer.WriteLine("file content blah blah blahh");
            writer.Flush();
            stream.Position = 0; // read from the start of what was written

            message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(stream, "filename.csv", "text/csv"));

            mailClient.Send(message);
         }
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip sir. I already refactor my code. I have one more question, so I've removed using `using` statement, can I dispose the stream in other class that uses it? like after sending an email, I want to dispose it. Is it okay to use something like `dto.FileStreamFile.Dispose();` based from my code above

Comment: @AppleCiderYummy yes that would work, and you definitely want to dispose it, possibly in a try finally in case there is an exception for some reason. However if possible i would steer away from having a `FileStream` as a property of a `DTO` it would be better to load the file stream in the method you need it, and putting it in `using` statement there.

Comment: I understand. But my email sending doesn't work after I put a `using` statement covering the sending of email with `stream`